# Koa websocket to websocket

Tags: websocket, koa

I have a node.js server that takes data from a "sleepy" client over a websocket, then tries to push that data to the web client via its websocket.   Sleepy means that it sleeps for a few minutes then wakes up to take a measurement and push the data, then back to sleep.  See below:

sleepy client --> websocket--> node.js server --> websocket --> web clients

There is only one sleepy client but there can be multiple web clients.  So when new data arrives, I need to push it to all web client web sockets.  To keep track of this, I have an array that track web clients and stores their ctx info for later.

**But**, and this is the problem, when I try to push data to the web client websocket, I get a context error and node.js crashes.

Here is my code:

```
var globalCtx = [];
app.ws.use( function( ctx, next ) {
    ctx.websocket.on('message', function ( message )
    {
        if( "telemetry" in jsonMsg )
        {
            console.log( "Got Telemetry: " );
            console.log( message.toString() );
            // we just got a telemetry message,
            // so push it to the all the web client websockets
            globalCtx.forEach( (myCtx, next) => {
                console.log( "DEBUG: ", util.inspect(myCtx) ); <<<-----crashes here
                myCtx.send( jsonMsg );                 <<<----- or crashes here when not debugging
            });
        }
        else
        if( "webClient" in jsonMsg )
        {
            console.log( "Got WS Client: " );
            console.log( message.toString() );

            // we just got a web client connection message
            // so store its context for pushing to later

            if( Array.isArray( globalCtx ) && globalCtx.length )
            {
                // search for an existing entry
                for( let idx = 0; idx < globalCtx.length; idx++ )
                {
                    if( globalCtx[ idx ].ip == ctx.ip )
                    {
                        // we already have this IP stored, do nothing
                        console.log("IP already found: ", ctx.ip );
                        //return next( ctx );
                        return;
                    }
                }

                // we made it here, this means that the IP wasn't found
                console.log("not found, adding IP: ", ctx.ip );
                globalCtx.push( ctx );
            }
            else
            {
                // the array is empty, so just add it
                console.log("empty array adding IP: ", ctx.ip );
                globalCtx.push( ctx );
            }
        }
    });
    return next(ctx);
});
```

Here is the error:

```
/home/pi/node_modules/koa/lib/response.js:73
    return this.res.statusCode;
                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
    at Object.get status [as status] (/home/pi/node_modules/koa/lib/response.js:73:21)
at /home/pi/node_modules/only/index.js:6:20
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at module.exports (/home/pi/node_modules/only/index.js:5:15)
at Object.toJSON (/home/pi/node_modules/koa/lib/response.js:                                                                  562:12)
at Object.toJSON (/home/pi/node_modules/koa/lib/context.js:5                                                                  1:31)
at Object.inspect (/home/pi/node_modules/koa/lib/context.js:                                                                  33:17)
at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:745:19)
at Object.inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:319:10)
at /home/pi/koaThermostat/index2.js:46:46
```

Here is the error from the `myCtx.send( jsonMsg );` line

```
/home/pi/koaThermostat/index2.js:47
                myCtx.send( jsonMsg );
                      ^
TypeError: myCtx.send is not a function
    at /home/pi/koaThermostat/index2.js:47:23
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I feel silly!  When using the Koa context with websockets, you have to use the websocket object.  So in my case it should have been `myCtx.websocket.send()` not `myCtx.send()`.
Now I'm on to my next bug....